# Closed form formula for series involving derivatives of reciprocal gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, special-functions

How to get closed form for the sum $\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{p^k}}}
{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}\frac{{{d^k}}}
{{d{s^k}}}{{\left. {\frac{1}
{{\Gamma \left( s \right)}}} \right|}_{s = \frac{3}
{2}}}} }$ for $0 < p \leqslant 1$? For $p=1$, I have managed to obtain (numerically and by guesswork) $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}
{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}\frac{{{d^k}}}
{{d{s^k}}}{{\left. {\frac{1}
{{\Gamma \left( s \right)}}} \right|}_{s = \frac{3}
{2}}}}  = 1 - \frac{1}
{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{3}
{2}} \right)}}$ which would imply $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}
{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}\frac{{{d^k}}}
{{d{s^k}}}{{\left. {\frac{1}
{{\Gamma \left( s \right)}}} \right|}_{s = \frac{3}
{2}}}}  = 1$. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Since $(2k)!!=2^k k!$ the series is the Taylor series expansion of $1/\Gamma((3+p)/2)$ at $p=0$

Comment: So the answer would be $\frac{1}
{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{{3 + p}}
{2}} \right)}} - \frac{1}
{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{3}
{2}} \right)}}$. Thank you, very clever, I'm tired so didn't see it. If you want to make it into the answer, I will accept it and upvote it

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By writing $(2k)!!$ as $(2k)!!=2^k k!$ the series becomes
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^k \left.\frac{d^k}{ds^k}\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\right|_{s=\frac{3}{2}} 
$$
which is by definition the Taylor series expansion of 
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3+p}{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}
$$
at $p=0$.